# Node JS and Mouse

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to assess the feasibility of the following setup using node js as a mouse recorder. I know that there are simple JS mouse recorders with timers and arrays, but they are not efficient enough when it comes to timing (due to ms deviations in the js timer class).

Lets assume I want to be able to do the following:

1) Instead of pushing the current mouse position every change, I want to buffer it locally and push the data in a set interval (e.g. 5sec). Is that even possible?

2) If so, the stream of this mouse movement is saved as a binary file. The binary file could then be streamed to another client.

Generally I have a difficulty in understanding streams in general. To my understanding streams are just chunks of data that are sent to the client. Is this correct?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your reason to use node.js, as that is used to power the *server*.  It plays no part in the actual capturing of the mouse data.

Comment: I want to use this approach to decouple mouse recoding lag issues from the performance of the computer the js recorder would be running on. If you record the mouse with a simple js timer + array write, the  inaccuracy of the js timer will make a difference in playback if the client's pc has less recourses to spare for the playback. This can lead to a delay, i.e. inaccurate playback

Comment: Node.JS is a console world, itself it can catch only OS events via C/C++ wrappers. So I guess this is not a question about handling event, but getting this event with smallest delay from browser. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, its possible, I would recommend you to use Event Emitter <-> Event Listener logic.

2) Sure, you can do it. But tell us more clear about what are you trying to do. Meanwhile you can take a look into [socket.io](http://socket.io) solution for streaming data, or [npm install ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws). Again , it very depends of what you're tying to develop.

Also there are much more complex and powerful solutions based on RTMP protocol, but I've no idea why you will need it here to send couple of bytes from one side to another. Also you may take a look to broadcaster idea, if you have to send those data chunks to multiple subscribers.

Comment: The main reason for this approach is that js performance mouse playback based on a the js timer class is not accurate enough (~5ms) especially when coupled with streamed media like audio from rtmp protocols. Thats why i thought a simultaneous stream of a given audio and mouse format could eliminate those timer issues as the information come as a 'bundle' to the client.

Comment: you should act on OS level, or at least on Browser level. Cause embedded javascript engine of any DOM renderer, would have that delay for any event handler, regards ECMA specification. So its not question about Transport Layer at the moment, but decreasing delay of getting these events' data. So I would recommend you to deal with WebKit sources, or some native libraries of OS to get smallest delay of getting information about mouse position and states.

Comment: Yes you are right, the 'render' action for a mouse cursor would always be prone to those timing issues. My though was that the delay is 'synced' when streaming both media types simultaneously rather than doing a rtmp playback from a Flash player in the background plus a mouse playback from js (i.e. having two 'clocks' acting independently).

Comment: Im not sure I'm understudying what are you trying to do. Are you trying to show mouse position on 2 separate browsers (separate computers) simultaneously?

Comment: No, i know its probably confusing. I'm trying to record the mouse continuously and then push it to the server. Another user can then stream the mouse to his computer together with an audiotrack (its basically like a video but instead its an audio and mouse layer). I'm not sure if this will circumvent the timer issues though.